# Browser not rendering response on successful Django redirect

Tags: javascript, python, django, redirect

My goal here is to check what type of user has logged in. If the user is of type "special", then I want to redirect that user to a separate page called dashboard (who's view is in a separate app). If the user is not special, the regular success page will rendered.

The case for the regular user works perfectly, but the case for special users fails. From using a debugger and Chrome's web inspector, I've noticed that Django performs the redirect successfully, and returns the correct HTML response to the browser, but the browser takes no action in displaying that page. The network tab on Chrome's web inspector shows two distinct requests made to the server- the original login request, and the request for the redirect to the dashboard.

What should I be doing to ensure the browser displays the dashboard?

Here is the login function in views.py:

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_home(request, {'login_required': True})
    errors = []
    email = request.POST['email']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            auth_login(request, user)
        else:
            errors = ["User isn't active"]
    else:
        errors = ["User couldn't be authenticated"]

    if (user.is_special):
        url = reverse('special.views.dashboard')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
    template = loader.get_template('users/login.js')
    context = Context({"errors": errors})
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context), mimetype="text/javascript")
```

Here is the dashboard function in the special app's views.py:

```
@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    user = request.user
    special_data = get_special_data(user)
    data = {'user': user, 'special_data': special_data}
    return render(request, 'special_dashboard.html', data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning javascript from the view in the normal case, this suggests you are using ajax to handle the login form. If this is the case, you need to handle the redirection on the client side, too.

Comment: Thanks, you were right! Instead of redirecting via Django, I decided to redirect by setting the window.location.href variable in the existing javascript response.